# Where is IsSelfRegistrationEnabled set in abp framework?

Tags: abp

In the ABP Framework, the Login.cshtml page has this line:

```
@if (await SettingProvider.IsTrueAsync(AccountSettingNames.IsSelfRegistrationEnabled))
```

How can this setting be changed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Identity server project, in the file `appsettings.json`, set the key `Abp.Account.IsSelfRegistrationEnabled` with the value `false`.

```
{  
  "Settings":
  {
      "Abp.Account.IsSelfRegistrationEnabled": "false" 
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It's set in the `AccountSettingDefinitionProvider`which is part of the Account Module

> ..\abp\modules\account\src\Volo.Abp.Account.Application\Volo\Abp\Account\Settings\AccountSettingDefinitionProvider.cs

```
namespace Volo.Abp.Account.Settings
{
    public class AccountSettingDefinitionProvider : SettingDefinitionProvider
    {
        public override void Define(ISettingDefinitionContext context)
        {
            context.Add(
                new SettingDefinition(
                    AccountSettingNames.IsSelfRegistrationEnabled, 
                    "true", 
                    L("DisplayName:Abp.Account.IsSelfRegistrationEnabled"), 
                    L("Description:Abp.Account.IsSelfRegistrationEnabled"), isVisibleToClients : true)
            );

            context.Add(
                new SettingDefinition(
                    AccountSettingNames.EnableLocalLogin, 
                    "true", 
                    L("DisplayName:Abp.Account.EnableLocalLogin"), 
                    L("Description:Abp.Account.EnableLocalLogin"), isVisibleToClients : true)
            );
        }

        private static LocalizableString L(string name)
        {
            return LocalizableString.Create<AccountResource>(name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have the AccountSettingDefinitionProvider class in my project. I assume it's being referenced in a Nuget package. In order to set IsSelfRegistrationEnabled to false, do I need to create a new class called something like MyAccountSettingDefinitionProvider and set it to false, or is there a better way to do it? Thank for your help